# Java get a date by the given day name

Tags: java, date

How can I get a date by day's name?

For example:

```
Input: Monday
Output: 02/08/2021

Input: Tuesday
Output: 03/08/2021
```

I want to get the closest date of the day.

Comment: What did your search bring up? I hope you will find pages advising the use of `DayOfWeek` and `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: By "closest" do you mean the closest from today?

Comment: Closest non-past day (up to 6 days into the future) or closest regardless of future or past (at most 3 days away from today)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to find the closest day *from today* that has a specific day of week, one way to do this is to compute both the next and previous day from today that has that day of week, and compare them:

```java
private static LocalDate closestDOW(DayOfWeek dow) {
  LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
  LocalDate next = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(dow));
  LocalDate previous = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(dow));
  if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, next) < ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(previous, today)) {
    return next;
  } else {
    return previous;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, work out whether the next such day is at most three days away. If it is, then it is closer than the previous such day.

```java
private static LocalDate closestDOW(DayOfWeek dow) {
  LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
  int daysDiff = today.getDayOfWeek().getValue() - dow.getValue();
  int daysUntilNextDOW = daysDiff >= 0 ? 7 - daysDiff : -daysDiff;
  if (daysUntilNextDOW <= 3) {
    return today.plusDays(daysUntilNextDOW);
  } else {
    return today.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(dow));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of what the OP wants -

> Given a day of the week as input, print the date (having the same day of the week as the input) which is closest to today.

We can do this using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) and [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html).

The logic is -

- Convert the input day of week to an instance of `DayOfWeek`.
- If today is the same day of week as the input, print today's date and stop, else proceed to the next steps.
- Get the date of the same day of the week in the previous week.
- Get the date of the same day of the week in the next week.
- Check which day is closer to today by using [`.toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--).

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputDayOfWeekString = "SUNDAY";
    DayOfWeek inputDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.valueOf(inputDayOfWeekString);
    
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    if (today.getDayOfWeek().equals(inputDayOfWeek)) {
        System.out.println(today);
    } else {
        LocalDate sameDayNextWeek = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(inputDayOfWeek));
        LocalDate sameDayPreviousWeek = today.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(inputDayOfWeek));
        LocalDate dateCloserToToday = (sameDayNextWeek.toEpochDay() - today.toEpochDay()) < (today.toEpochDay() - sameDayPreviousWeek.toEpochDay()) ? sameDayNextWeek : sameDayPreviousWeek;
        System.out.println(dateCloserToToday);
    }
}
```